# FP Growth can't start

Tags: weka, fpgrowth

My datasets is in [UCI Datasets](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/320/student+performance) student-mat.csv

Now, I want to use FP Growth, but it displays in gray color, however, I transfer data format to binary.

This is my step.

1. Choose→weka →filters →unsupervised→attribute →NumericToNomial -> apply
2. Choose→weka →filters →unsupervised→attribute →NomialToBinary -> Class(NoClass)-> apply
3. Choose→weka →filters →unsupervised→attribute -> NumericToBinary -> ignoreClass=True -> OK -> apply

It still displays in gray color, why? How should I do ?

Comment: Do you still have STRING attributes in your data? If yes, convert them using the [StringToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) filter.